Inserting dynamic data to redshift using eventbridge pipe
I've been using aws eventbridge to create a pipe that has a kinesis source, everything good with the source, filtering and enrichment. But when i try to send the information to redshift it just won't work. The logs say that everything is ok but the new data is not showing in redshift.
The query i'm using is INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('11234124321', '13123123' ,'test', $.data); data has only a 'hello world!' string to test. This insert is not working but if instead i use something like INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('11234124321', '13123123' ,'test', 'test1'); the new row is inserted with no problems in redshift.
I've been reading documentation for hours and even gave aws ia a try but with no luck. Also tried to use target input transformer with the same result.
A list of everything i've tried:
INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('5', json_extract_path(to_json('$context.event.detail'), '$.data.status'), 'test', 'test1')
INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('6', $.data.status, 'test', 'test1')
INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('7', $.status, 'test', 'test1')
INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('8', json_extract_path(to_json('$context.event.detail'), '$.status'), 'test', 'test1')
INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('9', json_extract_path(to_json('event.detail'), '$.status'),to_json('event.detail'), 'test', 'test1')
INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('10', JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT('$context.event.detail','data', 'status'), 'test', 'test1')
INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('11', json_extract_path(input, 'status') ,'test', 'test1');
INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('11234124321', '13123123' ,'test', TO_CHAR($));


This sounds like it might be a COMMIT issue (everything works but no data is showing up).  The database doesn't permanently store the changes w/o a COMMIT and doesn't allow another session to see changes that are committed until that session is brought up to date with a COMMIT or ROLLBACK.
So this leads to several questions.

What logs are you reviewing?
How are you checking that the data changes aren't in the database?
Can you see the SQL you are issuing in the redshift catalog tables (like stl_querytext)?
How are you inserting the set of data that is working? Using a workbench session?
What COMMITs are you sending and what COMMIT settings are there on your connections to the database?

On a side note and since you are using Kinesis, there's a good chance you expect this solution to scale to high volume.  The issue you will run into is that inserting data this way into Redshift is very non-performant and can actually over stress the cluster making other work slow down.  You should look into batching the data and loading through S3 using a COPY like firehose does.

Hi Bill, thanks for answering. I'm reviewing the pipe logs, the target's request looks like this for my last tests "awsRequest": "{\"clusterIdentifier\":\"cluster\",\"database\":\"database\",\"dbUser\":\"user\",\"secretArn\":null,\"sqls\":[\"INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('123', '13123123', 'test', '<$.data>');\"],\"statementName\":\"test_redshift\",\"withEvent\":true,\"workgroupName\":null}" and the response {\"clusterIdentifier\":\"cluster\",\"createdAt\":17,\"database\":\"db\",\"dbUser\":\"user\",\"id\":\"2\",\"secretArn\":null}

Also i don't think is a COMMIT issue since from the target i have inserted data like INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('11', 'a' ,'test', 'test1'); and no COMMIT and when i select all the data in the table from the query editor v2 the new row is there. So i insert the data that is working from the eventbridge pipe and check it from the query editor.
Also thanks for your suggestion on performance, i'll look into batching the inserts so i don't get the performance issues

Can you see the insert in question in the catalog tables?  This will show what actually was issued to Redshift.  I can help you put together the full list of commands issued by the session which can be helpful.  Just let me know.

Batching INSERTs is helpful as it brings down the number of statements issued but you really need to be using COPY for moving large amounts of data to Redshift.  Not sure this was clear in my answer.  (Data in the statements means that the query compiler is processing the data which just isn't efficient no matter how big the batches are.)

I was able to see the inserts in the catalog tables but all looks like this INSERT INTO public.event_bridge_test (id, status, test, test1) VALUES ('11234124321', '13123123', 'test', '<$.data>'); (With the dynamic string between simple quotes).
For me it looks like some problem with the way the dynamic params are passed to redshift. And yes that comment you made really got me thinking about my solution. It's for an event based system so there would be a lot of data but not concurrently

This is a common tension - real-time vs. highly efficient querying.  You can set up a system that loads to Redshift every 1, 2, or 5 min.  Depending on how much latency from real time you solution can tolerate. Bigger is better but small batches can make things efficienty enough to meet the requirements.  Otherwise you need to pair up a real-time db for recent data with Redshift for the historical analysis - a much more complicated solution.
